# Simulink Support Package for Android Devices Error: "not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: matlab, simulink

In the hardware setup of MATLAB Simulink Support Package for Android Devices, I am getting this error while setting up:

> Error: "'D:\Android\Android' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ", on executing command 'D:\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.4\bin\gradle -v'.

[image]

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it wasn't reading your directory properly. Notice how you targeted your directory at `D:\Android\Android Studio` but the error is trying to recognize it as `D:\Android\Android`. Perhaps you need to get rid of the space in between `Android` and `Studio` and replace it with an arbitrary character. Maybe try `_` or make it a single word.